# 'Stories' menu option under Open Graph is missing in my facebook app

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api

I want to create custom stories on my facebook app and I was going through this below tutorial.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/creating-custom-stories/

But there was not such as "Stories" option under Open Graph in my facebook app. Please see this image:

http://www.screencast.com/t/eHGL9Mn65

How I can use 'Stories' option in my facebook app